# C Programming 2D Array Problems

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array, 2d

I am learning C before I start learning C++ so I am very new to programming. I was playing around with 2D arrays and I sort of understand it. However I can't seem to figure out how to do this:

`int x, y, z[4][4], i, j;`

Where x = 10, and y = 10;

```
for (i=0; i<4; i++)
{
  for(j=0;j<4;j++)
  {
    z[i][j]=z[x][[y];
  }
}
```

I want the output to be:

When `i=0` and `j=0` print z[x][y]; As in print 10, 10.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Doing `z[x][[y]` when `x=10, y=10` is not correct as `z[4][4]` ie. only of 4x4 elements.

Comment: I think you may have some confusion about multi-dimensional arrays. z[i][j] will contain only one value, and you set it by using z[i][j] = 10 (or x, or y, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

You're setting z[i][j] to be equal to z[x][y]. X and Y are 10 and 10 respectively which is outside the bounds of the array so that's going to fail

Answer (score 0):

Here `z[i][j]` is just one value so it prints only 10 and you have to assign like this:

```
for (i=0; i<4; i++)
{
   for(j=0;j<4;j++)
   {
     z[i][j]=x;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By doing `z[4][4]` you are declaring z as `4x4` matrix.

And when you try to use `z[x][[y]; eg z[10][10];` you are clearly accessing elements **out of bounds of your matrix.**

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int x, y, z[4][4], i, j;
    int base = 65536;

    for (i=0; i<4; i++){
        for(j=0;j<4;j++){
            int v;
            x = 10 + i;
            y = 10 + j;
            v = x * base + y;
            z[i][j] = v;
        }
    }
    i = 0;
    j = 0;
    if(i == 0 && j == 0)
        printf("%d, %d\n", z[i][j]/base, z[i][j] % base);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My understanding of a 2d array is definitely wrong. So I'll approach this question another way. Say I have the following variables.

int student_id[10], course_id[5];

int student_course[10][2];

There can only be 10 students.
There can only be 5 courses.
A student can only take 2 courses.

```
/*prompt user for student id*/

/*
say that the value for: 
student_id[0]=123
*/

/*prompt user for course id*/

/*
say that the value for:
course_id[0]=101
course_id[1]=102
course_id[2]=103
course_id[3]=104
course_id[4]=105
*/
```

What I want to print out is the student_course[value of student_id][value of course_id].

So I thought of doing it this way:

```
int student_id[10], course_id[5], student_course[10][2]

int i, j, k;

for(i=0; i<10;i++){
    for(j=0; j<5; j++){

        /*prompt user for student id*/
        printf("Enter User ID: ");
        scanf("%d", &student_id[i]);

        /*prompt user for course id*/
        printf("Enter Course ID: ");
        scanf("%d", &course_id[j]);

        for(k=0; k<2; k++){
            student_course[i][j]=student_course[i][k];
        }

    }
}
```

If this is the wrong way, what is the correct way to get the results I want? A 3 dimensional array perhaps? I might not be ready for that yet.